# AppleScript: how to check if folders/files starting with a string exist?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to check if any directory exists in a folder that starts with "A" and then list all these folders into a variable.

I must do an "if exists ..." check at first, otherwise I get an error when setting the variable if no folder exists starting with "A" in the given directory.

Here is my AppleScript code:

```
property libraryPath : (path to library folder from user domain) as string

tell application "Finder"
    if exists (folder in folder libraryPath whose name begins with "A") then
        set folderlist to name of every folder in folder libraryPath whose name begins with "A"
    else
        set folderlist to {}
    end if
    
    get name of every folder in folder libraryPath whose name begins with "A"
end tell
```

The results are:

```
tell application "Finder"
    exists folder of folder "Mojave EXT:Users:devtest:Library:" whose name starts with "A"
        --> false

    get name of every folder of folder "Mojave EXT:Users:devtest:Library:" whose name starts with "A"
        --> {"Accounts", "Application Scripts", "Application Support", "Assistant", "Assistants", "Audio", "Autosave Information"}
end tell
```

As you see, the strange thing is that I got `false` as the result for checking the existence of folders starting with "A", but then again I can get all the existing folders right after it.

Why? What do I do wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exists` command tells you whether some particular Finder object exists. However, the `folder in folder libraryPath whose...` query returns an AppleScript **list** of Finder objects, and a list is not *itself* a Finder object, so the command returns 'false'.

You can fix it by adding the `some` keyword as follows:

```
property libraryPath : (path to library folder from user domain) as string

tell application "Finder"
    if exists (some folder in folder libraryPath whose name begins with "A") then
        set folderlist to name of every folder in folder libraryPath whose name begins with "A"
    else
        set folderlist to {}
    end if
    
    get name of every folder in folder libraryPath whose name begins with "A"
end tell
```

The `some` keyword returns a random folder that starts with an 'A', if one exists, and the `exists` command recognizes it as a Finder object.

However, you don't really need to use `exists` here.  You can just use:

```
property libraryPath : (path to library folder from user domain) as string

tell application "System Events"
    set folderlist to name of every folder in folder libraryPath whose name begins with "A"
end tell
```

System Events is both faster and more reliable than the Finder for most things, and it will return an empty set if it doesn't find any matching items.

Comment: Minor quibble: 'folder of folder …' generates an error 1728 for me. 'folders of folder…' generates a list (albeit slowly — 4 sec vs .25 sec for your solution). This is the reason for the 'false' as far as I can tell.

Comment: Q: Why make libraryPath text/string when you can just use the native alias, which makes for yet quicker execution (.02 sec vs .25)?

Comment: @Mockman: No reason except that I copied the original code without thinking about it.

Comment: However if I remove "as string" then I get this: error "System Events got an error: Can’t make alias \"Mojave EXT:Users:devtest:Library:\" into type integer." number -1700 from alias "Mojave EXT:Users:devtest:Library:" to integer

Comment: Finally, I ended up with this:    set folderlist to name of every folder in library folder whose name begins with "A"

Comment: Assuming that you're running the second code block in the answer… 'folder libraryPath' is redundant (because you're now working with an alias rather than a string). Remove the 'folder' before 'libraryPath' and it should work.

Comment: @DevyV That should work as well. It's essentially integrates your property statement into your set statement.